# Center image in the middle of list with 50% overhang

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, html-lists

I am  trying to get my image to center in the middle of my four list items (2 either side), however when trying to get it to work the list items just go below the image! I want the image to be responsive so if the page gets smaller then say 1000px it will simply move into the right place (i understand that will need to be done with different media screens.

Note: I am using CoolKitten One Page website framework as I have no understanding of Javascript

[Live Demo](http://www.brandnewclub.com/dev/)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43AkV/)

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no">
    <title>Brand New Club</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> -->
    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="container clearfix">

            <div id="nav" class="grid_9 omega">
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li data-slide="1">Home</li>
                    <li data-slide="2">About Us</li>
                        <div id="logo">
                            <img src="http://www.brandnewclub.com/images/brand-new-club-logo-final.png">
                        </div>
                    <li data-slide="3">Services</li>
                    <li data-slide="4">Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="slide" id="slide1" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <div class="container clearfix">

            <div id="content" class="grid_7">
                <h1>Top Slide</h1>
                <h2>Get ready to make magic!</h2>
                <p>Remember that this is a BETA version. This is my first framework so if you see any issue please <a href="mailto:jalxob@gmail.com">let me know it</a>. </p>
                <p>Don't forget to follow me!</p>
                <p><a href="https://twitter.com/Jalxob" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a> <a href="http://dribbble.com/jalxob" target="_blank"><img src="images/dribbble.png"></a></p>
            </div>
            <div id="decorative" class="grid_5 omega">
                <img src="images/decorative.png">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="slide" id="slide2" data-slide="2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <div class="container clearfix">

            <div id="content" class="grid_12">
                <h1>Parallax Scrolling</h1>
                <h2>What you've seen its called parallax scrolling</h2>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="slide" id="slide3" data-slide="3" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <div class="container clearfix">

            <div id="content" class="grid_12">
                <h1>Grid</h1>
                <h2>See how the grid changes when you resize your screen</h2>
            </div>

            <div id="test" class="grid_1">1</div> <div id="test" class="grid_11 omega">11</div>
            <div id="test" class="grid_2">2</div> <div id="test" class="grid_10 omega">10</div>
            <div id="test" class="grid_3">3</div> <div id="test" class="grid_9 omega">9</div>
            <div id="test" class="grid_4">4</div> <div id="test" class="grid_8 omega">8</div>
            <div id="test" class="grid_5">5</div> <div id="test" class="grid_7 omega">7</div>
            <div id="test" class="grid_6">6</div> <div id="test" class="grid_6 omega">6</div>
            <div id="test" class="grid_7">7</div> <div id="test" class="grid_5 omega">5</div>
            <div id="test" class="grid_8">8</div> <div id="test" class="grid_4 omega">4</div>
            <div id="test" class="grid_9">9</div> <div id="test" class="grid_3 omega">3</div>
            <div id="test" class="grid_10">10</div> <div id="test" class="grid_2 omega">2</div>
            <div id="test" class="grid_11">11</div> <div id="test" class="grid_1 omega">1</div>
            <div id="test" class="grid_12">12</div>

        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="slide" id="slide4" data-slide="4" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <div class="container clearfix">

            <div id="content" class="grid_12">
                <h1>Credits</h1>
                <h2><a href="http://jalxob.com/cool-kitten" target="_blank">Cool Kitten</a> was made by <a href="http://www.jalxob.com" target="_blank">Jalxob</a>.</h2>
                <p>Don't forget to follow me!</p>
                <p><a href="https://twitter.com/Jalxob" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a> <a href="http://dribbble.com/jalxob" target="_blank"><img src="images/dribbble.png"></a></p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.min.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
/* Global */

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #8a8683;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
a:link {
    color: #f68f67;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #bde2df;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #f68f67;
    text-decoration: none;
}





/* Navigation */

.menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    width:100%; 
    height:auto; 
    background-color:#bbb;
    z-index:100;
}
#logo {

    padding: 10px;

}
#logo img {
   width: 300px;
}
#nav {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    min-width: 1100px;
}
.navigation{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: -webkit-fit-content;
       width: -moz-fit-content;
            width: fit-content;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 200px;
}
.navigation li{
    padding:0 0 0 50px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
.navigation li:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #a9d3d0;
}

.navigation .active{
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #f68f67;
    font-weight:bold;
}


/* General Slides */ 

.slide{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    padding:140px 0;
}



/* Slide 1 */ 

#slide1{
    background-color:#156;
}
#slide1 h1 {
    font-size: 3.8em;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    line-height: 0px;
    color:#8a8683;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#slide1 h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #8a8683;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}




/* Slide 2 */ 

#slide2{
    background-image:url('../images/footprints.png');
    background-color:#f68f67;
    color:#ffffff;
}
#slide2 h1 {
    font-size: 3.8em;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    line-height: 0px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#slide2 h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}




/* Slide 3 */ 

#slide3{
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
#slide3 h1 {
    font-size: 3.8em;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    line-height: 0px;
    color:#8a8683;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#slide3 h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #8a8683;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#test{
    background-color:#bde2df;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 400;
}




/* Slide 4 */

#slide4{
    background-image:url('../images/sunglasses.png');
    background-color:#8a8683;
    color:#ffffff;
}
#slide4 h1 {
    font-size: 3.8em;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    line-height: 0px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#slide4 h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}





/* Tablet */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

#logo {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px 0;
}

.navigation{
    width: 100%;
    float: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.navigation li{
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    padding:0;
}

.slide{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    padding:150px 0;
}

#decorative {
    display:none;
}

#content {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}

#slide1 h1 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide1 h2 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide2 h1 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide2 h2 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide3 h1 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide3 h2 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide4 h1 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide4 h2 {
    line-height: 1em;
}

}




/* Mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

#logo {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav {
    width:100%;
    margin:5px 0;
}

.navigation{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.navigation li{
    float: left;
    width:25%;
}

.slide{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    padding:150px 0;
}


#slide1 h1 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide1 h2 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide2 h1 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide2 h2 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide3 h1 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide3 h2 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide4 h1 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
#slide4 h2 {
    line-height: 1em;
}


}
```

Any tips and advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it working for you using only CSS and not tables.

The way I saw best to do it was to split the lists and give one the property of `float:left` and the other `float:right`. I have to admit it is not the cleanest way of doing it but it works and for me that is the main thing.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/892Cz/)

**Note: This will work on the larger screens better then smaller, I would suggest using `media screen {}` in your CSS for this to work **

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I can see that working... Thank you for the advice too!

Answer (score 0):

I go for table in this context. Please find a sample.

```
 <table width="100%" border="1" style="height:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
    <tr><td>Home</td><td></td><td>About Us</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="1"></td><td style="background:url(deep-forest.jpg) no-repeat; background-size:100%;width:400px;"></td><td rowspan="1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Services</td><td></td><td>Contact</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Image: [image]

Let me know of any corrections.

Answer (score -1):

You could done this that way :

```
    #logo {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    #logo img {
        width: 300px;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: -150px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
    }
```

**[Everything is explained here](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/)**